# How to retry failed step in run-workers?

Tags: automated-tests, codeceptjs

I want to mix the advantages of run-workers (multiple agents to gain time) and run-rerun (fight against flaky tests) but I don't know how I can do that.

Currently, I do `npx codeceptjs run-workers --suites 5 --steps` but I have some flaky tests. I want to have the same feature of run-rerun with retry failed tests (minimum success, maximum reruns). Is it possible ?

What is the solution ? Somebody helps me, please.

Answer (score 0):

What about use the retryfailedstep plugin?
https://codecept.io/plugins/#retryfailedstep

You also could try other `retries` options:

- Auto retry
- Retry Step
- Retry Scenario
- Retry Feature

https://codecept.io/basics/#retries

Once you configure that, try to run your tests using `npx codeceptjs run-workers 5`